# insert semicolon every 2 bytes

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have an output like the following:

```
FA-7E 0 500009730007C118
FA-8E 0 500009730007C11C
FA-7F 0 500009730007C158
FA-10F 0 500009730007C164
```

that I would like to translate it into:

```
FA-7E 0 50:00:09:73:00:07:C1:18
FA-8E 0 50:00:09:73:00:07:C1:1C
FA-7F 0 50:00:09:73:00:07:C1:58
FA-10F 0 50:00:09:73:00:07:C1:64
```

please advise.

Comment: The regex in question is `[0-9A-F]{2}(?=[0-9A-F])`. I can't help with the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/../,"&:",$NF);sub(/:$/,"")}1' file
FA-7E 0 50:00:09:73:00:07:C1:18
FA-8E 0 50:00:09:73:00:07:C1:1C
FA-7F 0 50:00:09:73:00:07:C1:58
```

Comment: Could you explain what `1` at the end means?

Comment: awk scripts are a series of `<condition> { <action> }` statements that get evaluated for each record (line by default) in the input file. The default condition is `true` and the default action is `print the current record`, so if you just write an action statement like `{gsub(/../,"&:",$NF);sub(/:$/,"")}` then it gets executed as the missing condition before it is assumed to be true, and if you just write a constant like `1` where a condition should go then that's a true condition and so invokes the default `print` action.

Answer (score 1):

Sed solution:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/\1:/g' -e 's/:\([- ]\|$\)/\1/g'
```

The first substitution adds : after each pair of hex digits, the second one removes the extra colons from the first column and the end of line.

Comment: Thanks but this will also substitute chars like `10H`.

Comment: @leafei: Where do you expect the characters to appear?

Comment: @leafei: Please post an example with the desired output.

Comment: sorry I didn't make the question clear, the first column may have chars like `FA-10F`.

Answer (score 0):

A perl variation:

```
perl -pe 's/\w\w(?=\w+$)/$&:/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

not the best but works:

```
perl -lane 'push @a,$F[2]=~/../g;$F[2]=join ":",@a;undef @a;print "@F"' your_file
```